# Azure function API giving slow response

Tags: node.js, azure, performance, azure-functions

I am new to the Azure platform. I have written multiple functions in node js.
I am facing an issue for the slow function response from the function to get or add data. Sometimes it works fine.
Please let me know if there is any setting in Azure portal to fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to contain specifics: code, timing, type of Function App (consumption, app service plan), performance tier, where you're calling your Function from (e.g. from an app in the same region?), etc. Otherwise, there's really no way to answer this, aside from guessing.

Comment: What plan you are based on, and how slow the function response? This question need you offer more information.:)

Answer (score 0):

If your function runs on a consumption plan, it may lead to cold start of the function. After one request is processed, the instance stays alive for about 20 minutes(not exactly) to be reused for subsequent requests. After about 20 minutes, it will start slowly and wait a long to response.

To avoid this problem, you can choose a [premium plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan) for your function app. And use pre-warmed instances, it will improve the response time when your function not called for a long time. But it also means more cost.

[image]